# PHP Foreach - Different last row

Tags: php

I am using a foreach statement to echo the data I have out to a jquery chart (flotchart). The form needs to be `{"label", data},  {"label", data},  {"label", data}`

But my foreach statement adds a comma after every row including the last row which I can't have a comma because it is breaking the script.

I am currently using

```
foreach ($bycountry as $country) {print 
'{ label: "' . $country['origincountry'] . '", data: ' . $country['countrytotal']. ' }, ';
}
```

This gives me: `{"label", data},  {"label", data},  {"label", data},`

**I need no comma on the last row**

Comment: why are you writing json like that - just use json_encode(). Or is it not json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried just [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it?

```
$country_to_json = array(
    array('label'=>'Portugal', 'data'=>12), 
    array('label'=>'india', 'data'=>13) 
);

echo json_encode($country_to_json);
```

You'll need to reorganize your array a bit, but it is a much cleaner approach.

Another way is to use `implode`, however you'll need to reorganize your array anyway:

```
$country_for_implode = array();
foreach($bycountry as $country){
   $country_for_implode[] = "{ label: {$country['origincountry']}, data: {$country['countrytotal']}}";
}

echo implode(",", $country_for_implode);
```

Comment: I don't think it adds value to say "another way". It's the wrong way, and there are other answers which show that. Better to _just_ indicate the right way i.e. json_encode

Comment: It's a useful template anyway. I'm amazed how many people claiming they are skilled professionals are not aware of that approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$str = '';  
foreach ($bycountry as $country) {
$str .= '{ label: "' . $country['origincountry'] . '", data: ' . $country['countrytotal'].     ' }, ';
}
echo $str = substr($str, 0, strlen($str)-1);
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

just use this one

```
$temp = array();
foreach ($bycountry as $country) 
{
    $temp[] = '{ label: "' . $country['origincountry'] . '", data: ' . country['countrytotal']. ' } ';
}
print implode(",", $temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$no = 1;
foreach ($bycountry as $country) {
    if($no== 1)
    {
        print  '{ label: "' . $country['origincountry'] . '", data: ' . $country['countrytotal']. ' } ';
        $no ++;
    }
    else
    {
        print  ',{ label: "' . $country['origincountry'] . '", data: ' . $country['countrytotal']. ' } ';
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

use it like this

```
foreach ($bycountry as $country) {
$str .= '{ label: "' . $country['origincountry'] . '", data: ' . $country['countrytotal']. ' }, ';
}

$str = trim($str,",");
print $str;
```

This will remove last `,`

Answer (score 0):

with your array you can get the last key with something along these lines:

```
// Extract the last array item and return it's key value
$last_key = key(array_slice($bycountry, -1, 1, TRUE));

$out = '';

foreach ($bycountry as $key => $country)
{
    $out .= '{ label: "' . $country['origincountry'] . '", data: ' . $country['countrytotal']. ' }';

    // If this is not the last key
    if ($key !== $last_key)
    {
        // Add the trailing comma
        $out .= ',';
    }
}

print ($out);
```